# How to use AngularJS custom filter and lodash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, angular-filters

Using Angular v1.5.8 with lodash. I set up a custom filter on an array in ng-repeat. I have a checkbox too when it's checked, the filter will remove a certain element from the ng-repeat and when is unchecked, that element will be re-added to the ng-repeat.

Beside the checkbox condition, the filter contains applies angular's `filter` filter to always remove some elements.

The angular app:

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.newArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }])

.filter('simpleFilter', function($filter){
  return function(newArray,checked){
    newArray = $filter('filter')(newArray, '!4');

    if(checked){
      _.remove(newArray, function(elem){
      return elem == 2;
    });
    }
    return newArray;
  }
});
```

and the html:

```
<div ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">

  <span ng-repeat="el in newArray | simpleFilter:obj.checked">
    {{el}}
  </span>
<hr>
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="obj.checked">

  </div>
</div>
```

The example above working smoothly, but if I remove the default filter from the custom filter (this line: `newArray = $filter('filter')(newArray, '!4');`) and the checkbox is rechecked, the element hidden by _.remove will not reappear.

Here is the issue: https://codepen.io/neptune01/pen/rzbLmp

Comment: it is working for you ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai Yes, it's working. Sorry for the late answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `_filter` lodash method instead of `_remove`.

Unlike **_.filter**, `_remove` method mutates original array.

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.newArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
  }])
.filter('simpleFilter', function($filter){
  return function(newArray,checked){
    //newArray = $filter('filter')(newArray, '!4');
    if(checked){
      newArray=_.filter(newArray, function(elem){
      return elem != 2;
    });
    }
    return newArray;
  }
});
```

Here is [working solution.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oeOLOr)

You can also use `$filter` method in order to obtain a more **lighty** solution.

```
if(checked)
  newArray = $filter('filter')(newArray, '!2');
return newArray;
```